# Is it possible to convert input string with any format into date ios?

Tags: ios, nsdate

Is it possible to convert input string with any format into date?

I want to receive ate and time from textfield with any format like date: may 22 2000, wed may 20,    may, 30 2000 etc.. and also need to get correct value according to the local timezone.

please help?

Answer (score 0):

`NSDateFormatter` can help convert any type of date `NSString` to `NSDate`. The important thing is to use the right format for the date.

Here is some code you can try

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

You will have to set the date format to whatever format your string is in. Here are some date format specifiers: (Complete list **[here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns)**)

- `eeee` - Local day of week spelled out
- `yyyy` - year (4 digits)
- `MMMM` - Month spelled out
- `dd` - day of month with no leading zeros
- `HH` - hour of day (24 hour format)
- `mm` - minutes of hour (with leading zero)

---

*Edit*

The date format for the following dates will be:

- May 03 2000 : "MMM dd yyyy"
- Mon, Jan 03 : "eee, MMM dd"
- Mon 31 Jan : "eee dd MMM"

Comment: But if i need to accept strings-- May 3 2000  & Mon, Jan 3  and Mon 31 Jan, so it is not working when i tried with [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

Comment: Actually i need to accept strings in any format and convert to date. Is it possible? It is difficult to write diffrent time formats for every string i entered in the textfield

Comment: You have to set the `setDateFormat` according to your string. so for you it will be "MMMM dd yyyy"

Comment: If you don't know what format the date is coming in the string, I don't think it can be converted without giving the format to `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: I want to accept these 3 types of strings(mentioned above) and and convert in to date so i have to write 3 different formats?

Comment: Yes you will have to write the three formats, each for the appropriate date.

Comment: SO there is no other way? are you sure?

Comment: If you mean to convert a string to NSDate in such a way that you do not have to enter the format, then NO, there is no way.

Comment: I think you need to process the NSString and make it into a specific format , then convert it using NSDateFormatter

Comment: Actually my need is , to accept date from variety timezones and store and update. So in these case i have to write all timezone fromate?